# Distinct by multiple properties with specific conditions

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class Animal with three properties

```
class Animal {
  String name;
  String type;
  String color;
}
```

From a list of animals I need to find distinct animals.

The equality conditions are

1. if name is same both are equal
2. If both type and color are equal both are equal

So I wrote a wrapper animal and override the equals and hashcode

```
class WrapperAnimal {
    Animal insideDto;

    public WrapperAnimal(Animal dto) {
        this.insideDto = dto;
    }

    public Animal unwrap() {
        return insideDto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Animal dto = ((Animal) o).unwrap();

        if(dto.getName() != null && StringUtils.equals(dto.getName(), this.insideDto.getName())) {
            return true;
        }

        return StringUtils.equals(dto.getType(), this.insideDto.getType()) &&
                StringUtils.equals(dto.getColor(), this.insideDto.getColor());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(this.insideDto.getName())) {
            return Objects.hash(this.insideDto.getName());
        }

        return Objects.hash(this.insideDto.getType(),this.insideDto.getColor());
    }
}
```

I used streams distinct to find distinct

```
List<Animal> distinctAnimals = animals.stream().map(WrapperAnimal::new).distinct().map(WrapperAnimal::unwrap).toList()
```

This is not working when names are different but type and color are same.

| Name | Type | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tiger1 | type1 | yellow |
| tiger2 | type1 | yellow |

I understand this is issue with the hashcode function. How can I fix this?

Comment: It's because your hash method is not correct. Your hash is inconsistent.

Comment: I think your `equals` is incorrect too. It is not transitive. Can you explain in more detail about the two "equality conditions"?

Comment: you could reduce your equals conditions like this : `StringUtils.equals( dto.getName(), this.insideDto.getName()) || StringUtils.equals(dto.getType(), this.insideDto.getType()) && StringUtils.equals(dto.getColor(), this.insideDto.getColor());`

Comment: And in hashCode, just `Objects.hash(this.insideDto.getName(), this.insideDto.getType(),this.insideDto.getColor())`.

Comment: Btw you don't need a wrapper class for that.

Comment: Let’s say you have a) a red cat called Foo, b) a red cat call Bar and c) a green cat called Foo. a equals b, a equals c, but b is not equal to c => your equals method is not transitive, so you cannot have consistent logic. Bonus question: how many distinct animals do you have? If you start with a, you only have 1. If you start from b or c, you have 2.

Comment: @DidierL For this system, the data inconsistency is okay as long as there are no duplicates. And the rules are applied in the order of 1 and two in the order they are in the list